# Custom XKB layout before login

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, xkb, lubuntu, setxkbmap

[I have made a custom keyboard layout with XKB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654798/xkb-not-recognizing-my-custom-layout), but when I type my password on the login screen, the system still uses a QWERTY layout, only after the login my customized layout is applied. Is it possible to make Ubuntu 18.04 load my custom XKB layout before login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Quasímodo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/388654/quas%C3%ADmodo)! I modified the file `/etc/default/keyboard`, the line `XKBLAYOUT="br"` to `XKBLAYOUT="brc,br"` and it solved my issue.